# 2D Scrolling Game: Firing Bullets. Everything runs properly theres just no image

Tags: java, 2d-games

So heres some code to begin. I first created a class called Bullet. This is where the image should be loaded.

```java
package gameLibrary;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Bullet {

    int x,y;
    Image img;
    boolean visible;

    public Bullet(int startX, int startY) {
        x = startX;
        y = startY;

        ImageIcon newBullet = new ImageIcon("/resources/bullet.png");
        img = newBullet.getImage();
        System.out.println("constructor Bullet is called");
        visible = true;
    }
    public void move(){
        x = x + 1;
        if(x > 854){
            System.out.println("Bullet is moving at X = " + x);
            visible = false;  
        }
    }
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public boolean getVisible(){
        return visible;
    }
    public Image getImage(){
        return img;
    }
}
```

when the space bar is pressed it calls a method called fire() where a new Bullet(X, Y); is called and then stores it in an ArrayList.

```java
public void fire(){
    if(ammo > 0) {
        Bullet z = new Bullet(left + 60, y + 70);
        bullets.add(z);
        ammo--;
    }
}
public static ArrayList getBullets(){
    return bullets;
}
```

This code moves the bullet across the screen.

```java
ArrayList bullets = Character.getBullets();
for(int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++){
    Bullet m = (Bullet) bullets.get(i);
    if(m.getVisible() == true){
        m.move();
    }if(m.getVisible() == false) {
        bullets.remove(i);
    }
}
```

And Finally code for the print method.

```java
ArrayList bullets = Character.getBullets();
for(int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++){
    Bullet m = (Bullet) bullets.get(0);
    g2d.drawImage(m.getImage(),m.getX(),m.getY(), null);
}
```

I cant find where I went wrong. the functioning of the bullet is all working as far as I can tell its just the printing of the image on the screenAny suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo when I was fiddling with it. in the final code. the Bullet m = (Bullet) bullets.get(0); should be Bullet m = (Bullet) bullets.get(i)

Comment: Can you try adding something like `g2d.drawRectangle(m.getX(),m.getY(), 10, 10);` after you draw the bullet image.  Also, you should provide an `ImageObserver` to the `drawImage` so it can take care of any possible slow loading images ;)

Comment: Also where is `/resources/bullet.png` stored?  Is it an internal/embedded resource or file reference?

Comment: found it. it was ImageIcon newBullet = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/bullet.png"));

Comment: Good, you might like to check SpiderPig's answer as correct (for being the closest answer to your problem)

Answer (score 1):

Normally resources are loaded with Class.getResource

```
ImageIcon newBullet = new ImageIcon(Bullet.class.getResource("resources/bullet.png"));
```

Of course the resources folder should be in the same package (i.e. in the same folder) as your Bullet class.
That code should always work whether your game is in a jar or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think your resource path is not in the good format.

```
 ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("gameLibrary.resources.bullet.png");
```

if this doesn't work try this code to get your png path:

```
import java.io.File;  

public class GetPath  
{  
  public static void main(String[] args)  
  {  
    System.out.println("The user directory: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));  
    File fubar = new File("Fubar.txt");  
    System.out.println("Where Java thinks file is located: " + fubar.getAbsolutePath());  
  }  
}
```

Tell me what happens.

Comment: well I have an image for the background and an image for the character in the exact same format.... from the same resource package.

Comment: Could you paste the code where you create your `g2d` object instance?

Comment: which code are you talking about? the                           ImageIcon newBullet = new ImageIcon("/resources/bullet.png");
        img = newBullet.getImage();  ??

Comment: What does your `g2d` instance represents in `g2d.drawImage(m.getImage(),m.getX(),m.getY(), null);`?

Comment: Sorry thanks for your help! I found the error it was the path, I needed to use ImageIcon newBullet = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/bullet.png"));

Comment: Validate SpiderPig's as the answer in order to thank him for `getClass().getResource("/resources/bullet.png")`